# Load the Data table content to the Dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> LonView()
        {
            string sql = "SELECT Marks,Id FROM table4";
            using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection((@"DataSource")))
            {
                using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, Connection))
                {
                    Connection.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        dt.Load(myReader);
                        Connection.Close();
  Dictionary<string, object> lst = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                      var tableEnumerable = dt.AsEnumerable();
                        var tableArray = tableEnumerable.ToArray();
                foreach (var data in tableArray)
                        {
                      lst.Add(data["id"].ToString(),data["Marks"] as string);
                        }

return lst;
          }
      }
   }
}
```

I want to convert my Data table Column to  Dictionary and return the Dictionary in  Array{["A",30],["B",32],["C",45]} form.Suggest some ideas to do my Task.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this example:

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Marks", typeof(int));
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "A", 50 });
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "B", 100 });
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "C", 200 });

        Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            dict.Add(row[0].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(row[1].ToString()));
        }

        var arr = dict.ToArray();
```

Does this help you?

be sure that your query doesn't return duplicate ID values (key in your dictionary) because you'll get an exception.

Comment: Thanks for Your Response.,Actually the contents are loaded into the dictionary exactly .But one column act as a Key .I want to load without key .How to do?@ Nino

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create any `DataTable`, temporary `Dictionary`: a simple direct `while` loop will do

```
 string sql = 
   @"SELECT Marks,
            Id 
       FROM table4";

 using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection((@"DataSource"))) {
   using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, Connection)) {
     Connection.Open();

     // We don't know the final array's length; let's use a list as a buffer  
     List<string[]> buffer = new List<string[]>();

     using (SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()) {
       while (myReader.Read())
         buffer.Add(new string[] {
           Convert.ToString(myReader["id"]),
           Convert.ToString(myReader["Marks"]),
         });
     } 

     return buffer.ToArray(); 
   }         
 }
```

**Edit:** In case you want to preserve `DataTable` for some purpose

```
 using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection((@"DataSource"))) {
   using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, Connection)) {
     Connection.Open();

     using (SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()) {
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       dt.Load(myReader);

       // You can obtain the string[][] array via Linq: 
       string[][] result = dt
         .AsEnumerable()
         .Select(record => new string[] {
            Convert.ToString(record["id"]),
            Convert.ToString(record["Marks"]), })
         .ToArray();

       ...
     }
     ...
```

Comment: Yea,You are right .,But I need Data table for Some Purpose.Suggest some other Ideas.@Dmitry Bychenko

Comment: @monica: in this case (preserving `DataTable dt`) you can just obtain the jagged array via *Linq* (please, see my edit)

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```
dt.AsEnumerable()
      .ToDictionary<DataRow, string, object>(row => row.Field<string>(0),
                                row => row.Field<object>(1));
```

This will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple request :

```
        public static Dictionary<string, object> LonView()
        {
            string sql = "SELECT Marks,Id FROM table4";
            Dictionary<string, object> lst = null;
            using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection((@"DataSource")))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, Connection))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                    Connection.Close();
                    lst = dt.AsEnumerable()
                        .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Marks"), y => y.Field<object>("Id"))
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
                }
            }
            return lst;

         }
```

---

If value in database is a DateTime

```
        public static Dictionary<string, DateTime> LonView()
        {
            string sql = "SELECT Marks,Id FROM table4";
            Dictionary<string, DateTime> lst = null;
            using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection((@"DataSource")))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, Connection))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                    Connection.Close();
                    lst = dt.AsEnumerable()
                        .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Marks"), y => y.Field<DateTime>("Id"))
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
                }
            }
            return lst;

        }
```

Comment: Group By(x => x.Field<string>("XX"), y => y.Field<object>("YY")).                If XX is date time and YY is string then how to do this operation? @ jdweng

Comment: The type in angle brackets <> must be the same as the columns in the Database.  So in your case object would be y.Field<DataTime>("Id"), or DateTime.Parse(y.Field<string>("Id")) if you are converting a string to a DateTime.

Comment: I couldn't Understand .Can you please write it in a code form?

Comment: I updated code assuming the column in the database was DateTime.  Otherwise you need to parse the string into a DateTime.

Comment: Error:Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.DateTime>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>' @jdweng

Comment: You still have object some place in the code.  I changed code in 3 places.  I suspect the code that calls LonView() still has object.  If you double click on error in Error View it should show line where error is occurring.

Comment: Yea its working .But i don't want to set a key in dictionary ..Then what can i do to achieve?

Comment: I don't understand your issue.  A dictionary must have two items a key and a value.  The value can be a single items or a list of items.  The types for a key and the value can be nay type.  When getting dictionary values from a database the types must match the database types.  If the types don't match a conversion must be made before putting the data into the c# dictionary.

Comment: Actually am returning a dictionary to front end for Sme purposes.

Comment: So you want the key type to vary based on where it is used?  Then you need to put code into a class and specify the type as <T>.